# FB Gift Requests not appearing as Push Notification (Unity 3d Facebook SDK)

Tags: android, ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I am working on a game in Unity3D and I want to integrate facebook with it.
I want to be able to send a gift request for my app to a friend, but the thing is they appear in user's notification panel of Facebook but they don't appear in Notification Panel of my game. I want them to see a notification, like in Candy Crush(when someone receives a request in Candy Crush this also appears in the notification bar as push notification).

I want those requests to also appear in notification bar of the device, both Android and iOS. I need to know how they do it. Is there any service i can use or some processing from fb requests.

Answer (score 0):

The candy crush notifications are dispatched to the candy crush app itself, not by facebook. If you want to do so please have a look to Unity3D Push notifications.

Comment: but how do they do it meaning how do they come to know that a request has been received on facebook without opening application.